# Two way Binding in Some Angular Component is not working

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-forms, angular-ng-if, angular-module

In my angular project, I have many components but in some components, two-way binding is not working, It is always getting an error message for example:

```
Error: src/app/student/student.component.html:8:11 - error **NG8002: **Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'. <form [formGroup]="register">
```

But I have imported all the required things in ts files and module files. If I create a new component and paste the same code and delete this component it will work properly. Why is this abrupt behavior happening? What I can do to prevent it in my future projects? My lap is very old and it uses a Pentium processor and it has 4 GB ram capacity.

I tried to import the required files -in this case it is

```
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; and
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
```

I want a solution by which I can use the component without errors and without creating a new component

Comment: One component (not standalone) are declared in a module. Is in this module where you need import ReactiveFormsMoudel and FormControl. -if use standalone components in the imports array of the component. I don't know what can cause this effect :(

Comment: Please post complete, reproducible example and not just code fragments.

Comment: @E.Maggini I am new to stackoverflow I don't know how to add big code like this.I think you want to know all my component HTML,ts,and appmodule.ts files

Comment: @ABHIJITH https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example In this case, when you say "But I have imported all the required things in ts files and module files." WHERE have you imported them? Is student its own module? Is it part of a sub module.?  Creating a sparse minimum example will not only help get an answer but quite possible lead you to solving it yourself.  And here are some templates to get started. https://search.brave.com/search?spellcheck=0&q=stackblitz+how+to+create+reactive+form+example+in+angular